# How to share properties between AppDelegate and ViewController, and save before App is terminated

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a class with properties updated in viewController. I wanted to save the properties when the app goes into background or quit using AppDelegate. I used the following codes but it appears that the properties were not passed to the AppDelegate. Furthermore the applicationWillTerminate codes did not seem to get executed.

```
// testClass is defined and the properties are updated in viewController, e.g
testClass.status = true  // default is false

// I want to save testClass.status when the app goes into background or being terminated using the following:

 @UIApplicationMain

 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

 var vc = ViewController()     


 func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) { 

    print(vc.testClass.status)  //  prints false

    //codes to save
 }

    // save before App is terminated
 func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

     print(vc.testClass.status) // this code did not get executed?

   //codes to save
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applicationWillTerminate` is called only when a user terminates the app without switching it to background mode.

When the app is active, double press on Home button and terminate the app.

But if you switch the app to the background, and then try to terminate the app, `applicationWillTerminate` will not be called.

And you are creating an instance of `ViewController` in `AppDelegate`

`var vc = ViewController()`

If you change the testClass property in another `ViewController` class instance, you won't get that value here. So create a `singleton` class like this

```
class TestClass: NSObject {

    static let shared = TestClass()
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    var status = false
}
```

Now update the value in any view controller from the singleton class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController   {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TestClass.shared.status = true
    }
}
```

In `AppDelegate` save and retrieve the value from `UserDefaults`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        TestClass.shared.status = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Status")        
        return true
    }
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(TestClass.shared.status, forKey: "Status")
    }
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(TestClass.shared.status, forKey: "Status")
    }
}
```

---

Or create a computed property to save the value in UserDefaults whenever it is changed.

```
class TestClass: NSObject {
    static let shared = TestClass()
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    var status: Bool {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Status")
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "Status")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea using UserDefaults to pass data. The singleton class is not absolutely necessary, right? It only assures that there are not multiple instances existing elsewhere?

One clarification - the first function only execute at the beginning when the App loads, right? So when the status changes after the App is loaded, will it still work?

Comment: @Yan Using singleton class is best, because you don't need to create an instance for TestClass in every viewcontroller. If you create one TestClass instance in ViewController1 and another TestClass instance in ViewController2, Now both status properties aren't same. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method called at the app load. In applicationWillTerminate you save the value and in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you get that saved value

Comment: @Yan Check updated answer. By using a computed property, you don't need to save the value in applicationWillTerminate, applicationDidEnterBackground. It is automatically saved whenever you change its value. And you don't need to retrieve the saved value in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. It is automatically retrieved from the UserDefaults when you try to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by others you can ignore `applicationWillTerminate`.

To get notified when the app goes into the background just add an observer in the view controller.

However rather than `didEnterBackground` I'd recommend to observe `willResignActive`.

Add the observer in `viewDidLoad` once

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
        // save the properties
    }
}
```

Or if you are using multiple view controllers you can add the observer in `viewWillAppear` and remove it in `viewDidDisappear`

Side note:

Never create a view controller with the default initializer `ViewController()` if you are using storyboard. You'll get a brand new instance which is **not** the storyboard instance.